# indexOf stops after it finds the first string that matches but I want it to find the BEST string that matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

Essentially, I'm developing a chrome extension that looks at all the text on page and compares it to an array of names and if any of the `p` tags contains the value of the array then I do something..

The problem is quite simple really. My array is an associative array, and looks something like this:

```
"Blue": 'val0',
"Blue Orange": 'val1',
"Red": 'val2',
"Red White": 'val3'
```

and this is what my code looks like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
    if ($p.indexOf(arrayName[i].value) > -1) {
        validNames[arrayName[i].value] = arrayName[i].data;
    }
};
```

Now, everything works pretty much perfectly, apart from the fact that if `$p` contains the word `Blue Orange` it doesn't recognize `val1` but instead recognizes `val0` since it stops comparing after it finds the first `Blue`.

Is there anyway to fix this? I suppose one solution would be to put all the single word elements to the back of the array, but I'd prefer a less tedious method of fixing since my array has over 12,000 values.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you define your criteria for "best" match?

Comment: @sunny Not sure how to put this. if `blue` is in the `p` tag don't stop just because you have found a valid comparing stop because `blue orange` isn't available.. if that makes sense... probably not. If the word after `blue` is `orange` then `blue orange` is the valid element, if the word after `blue` isn't in the array just output `blue`... Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This is really not clear and it seems like something is missing. From what is shown there doesn't seem to be any reason both `Blue` and `Blue Orange` wouldn't be accounted for. A working example would help. Also a bit confusing using the term `array` when you are working with object

Comment: [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @charlietfl I'm highlighting the word on the page if it is within the array. I'm using indexOf to check if it is in the array and because of that it the for loop stops once it finds `blue` and therefore never makes its way to `blue orange` leaving the text on the website to be highlighted as `blue` when infact the text should be highlighting `blue orange`.

Comment: Nothing in loop shown breaks out of loop though unless you are modifying dom prior

Comment: @charlietfl it's just an example I have a few functions that are going on within the loop.

Comment: There's the whole problem with this question...your issues aren't in the code shown. No live demo given and therefore it's not answerable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be simple enough. Sort your array by length with longest first. In that case you will always find the longest match first.